# Exporting list of users and passwords securely in ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, password-management

I have a project in which I'm creating users with random passwords for a class of students, and I want to give this list to the teacher so he can distribute the user:pass to each student. What is the best way to do this outside of just saving it in plain text to a .txt file?

Right now it will likely be random alpha-numeric passwords and students cannot login to the shell, and are jailed to their home directory, so the accounts are pretty secure (I think). The accounts will only be used to SFTP web pages to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most portable ways, if everyone in your organization is using Linux, is to use OpenSSL to encrypt the file.

You can encrypt a file with:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in passwords.txt -out passwords.txt.enc
```

And decrypt it with:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in passwords.txt.enc -out passwords.txt
```

Of course you would write a wrapper script for this to make it easier for teachers to do.

You would have to distribute the password over a different channel. Alternatively you could also use GPG and use asynchronous encryption (public/private key):

```
gpg --output passwords.gpg --encrypt --recipient teacher@university.edu
```

And decrypt with:

```
gpg --output passwords.txt --decrypt passwords.gpg
```

But for this, you would have to set up GPG first, which might be complicated/inconvenient for non-tech savvy users.

Comment: Yeah the teacher has to run all his scripts through the shell so I'll likely do the openssl option. Thanks!